# can't get email from exchange to postfix

Tags: ssl, email, postfix, exchange

I configured a postfix mail server to receive emails.
I enable TLS as per security requirements as well as port 25 is banned by the provider.
I enabled both 465 and 587 with the following on master.cf

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

I can receive email from gmail, as well as others but exchange. I used an outlook client configured with an exchange account. I do not receive any incoming connection or logs into postfix.log file. It seems it is banned by the exchange server.
I also noticed that I can get certificate using openssl s_client -connect against 465 but if I do the same against 587 it returns an empty certificate.

Answer (score 5):

Mail is delivered on port 25. I am surprised that ANY MTA is delivering mail to your service - 465 and 587 are explicitly designated for mail submission (i.e. from a MUA, not delivery from a MTA). This is prescribed by [RFC 6409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409.html) & [8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314.html).

No port 25: No email.

Comment: RFC states that for relay communication nothing changed and it works on 25, however it seems, as proven by my tests with multiple MTAs, that most of them implemented TLS for relay communication as well. I'm 100% sure about 2 MTA I just tested, however I tested many of them in the past weeks and just exchange does not work. Probably it is an exchange prerogative, however I'm not 100% sure about it.
For that reason I do not agree with "No port 25: No email"

Comment: This is the correct answer. Most mail is delivered TLS encrypted using port 25. There's `STARTTLS` just like with the `587` submission port ([deprecated in RFC 8314](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8314)).

Comment: Agreed that port 25 is required if you want to receive from Exchange. Here's a similar threads for your reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/953086/blocking-port-25-cause-mail-server-cannot-receive-mail